# Gremlin Syntax to Query Cosmos Db Based on date

Tags: database, azure-cosmosdb, gremlin

Could you please guide me on how to write a gremlin query that will return only projects that have started past a specific date?

My first query returns all project vertices within program05:

*g.V('program05').has('partitionkey', 'program05').out('hasprojects')*

I would like to filter it down to return only projects that have started after '20/19/2018 4:37:12 PM' , a program vertex has a propertt of startDate

I have tried :

*g.V('program05').has('partitionkey', 'program05').out('hasprojects').has('startDate').has('startDate',gt, '20/19/2018 4:37:12 PM')*

but i get an Error: Unable to resolve symbol 'lt' in the current context. I have tried other opions too with no luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The predicate logic ([javadoc](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/current/core/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/process/traversal/P.html)) for strings seems to work based on ASCII values of the string, so your current storage of the date in text format will not work month over month.

I would suggest storing that as epoch seconds and then using the following query to get that data you want.

Assuming you meant the date `2/19/2018 4:37:12 PM`

```
g.V() 
 .has('partitionkey','program05')
 .out('hasprojects')
 .has('startDate',P.gt(1519058232))
```